# fileNotFound exception while starting glassfish 3

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, glassfish-3

I am getting the following message while starting glassfish server 3 in netbeans. How to amend this `fileNotFound` exception ?

```
Welcome to Felix
================

ERROR: Error creating archive. (java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Rajat\.netbeans\6.9\config\GF3\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\bundle136\version0.0\revision.location (The system cannot find the file specified))
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Rajat\.netbeans\6.9\config\GF3\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\bundle136\version0.0\revision.location (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.getFileInputStream(SecureAction.java:415)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive.getRevisionLocation(BundleArchive.java:706)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive.<init>(BundleArchive.java:206)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.getArchives(BundleCache.java:149)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:558)
        at org.apache.felix.main.Main.main(Main.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMainFelix$1.run(ASMainFelix.java:116)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug of the GlassFish bundle in NetBeans: 
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=196872
.

On the web you can find that it has been reported on NetBeans 6.8 and 6.9. I am running GlassFish bundled in NetBeans 7.0.1 (under Vista and Windows Server 2008) and have never had such issue.

I suggest to upgrade NetBeans or to override the GlassFish installation with the one available here: http://glassfish.java.net/public/downloadsindex.html#top .

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked just to delete the content of the folder "osgi-cache" and restart the server.
In this case it would be the content of the folder "C:\Users\Rajat.netbeans\6.9\config\GF3\domain1\osgi-cache"

I found the solution via Google there: http://www.java.net/node/698982